# How can I convert dates when uploading an excel sheet onto R?

Tags: r, excel

R is converting my excel sheet date column to numeric values when I upload it. The problem is that I have NA and random values to account for, but once I pass an if statement to get rid of them, it seems to be converting my values into negative numbers rather than date formats. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
  if (!is.na(dataset$date[i]) & grepl("-", dataset$date[i]) == FALSE){
    dataset$date[i] = as.Date(as.numeric(dataset$date[i]), origin = "1899-12-30")
  }
}
```

I have to convert the values as.numeric because they get stored as characters.
This is a small sample of what my data might look like

date
30816
30824
NA
28211
30646

And this is what it is being converted to after I run the script

date
5247
5255
2642
5077

This is the expected output I would like

date
1984-05-14
1984-05-22
NA
1977-03-27
1983-11-26

Comment: Can you provide a "snippet" of your data?

Comment: 37987, 39753, 41275, 39448 are some sample date values; it converts the values to 5247, 5255, 2642,  5077 instead of the actual dates

Comment: If you do `as.Date(dataset$date, origin = "1899-12-30")` it gives you the expected output for the dates that you have shared. See, `as.Date(c(30816,30824,NA,28211,30646), origin = "1899-12-30")`

Comment: I tried that but I kept getting errors that said that I needed to convert the values from a character to a numeric value. Additionally, it kept running into errors as it had a few NA and extraneous variables

Comment: So you have some dates with "-" in it. What do you want to do to them? Turn them to `NA` ?

Comment: I want to leave them the way they are

Comment: you cannot have values of different classes in the same column. "-" would be a character (or factor) so all the dates would turn into character class as well. These all cases should be included in your example along with showing their corresponding expected output.

Comment: actually after taking a closer look at the data it turns out the values seem nonsensical and can be converted to NA values

Comment: Then `as.Date(as.numeric(dataset$date), origin = "1899-12-30")` should work with a warning since `-` would automatically be converted to `NA` with `as.numeric`.